# how to use pywin32 sendmessage function to send a upper char or number char?

Tags: python, keyboard, pywin32, sendmessage

can any body help me ? when i use the follow function to send a lower char, a to z,  to a window, it work well. However, I don't know how to send a upper char, A to Z, or number char 0 to 9. I have test it many times.

```
def post_keys(hwnd, i):
    win32api.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, i, 0)
    win32api.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYUP, i, 0)
```

thans very much.

Comment: Maybe take a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280(v=vs.85).aspx .

Comment: thanks Hyperboreus. I look through the page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx and find that when the value of virtual-key codes is 0x41, it means the 'A' char. However, when I call the post_keys function and pass 0x41 to i, this function actually send a lowwer char 'a' to the hwnd window. can you help me to correct it ?

Answer (score 0):

Virtual-key code `0x41` represents the "A" key itself, not a specific case of the letter "A". If the Shift key is not currently pressed, it corresponds to lowercase "a". If the Shift key is pressed, it corresponds to uppercase "A".

For a letter to appear as uppercase, you have to send a first `WM_KEYDOWN` message with virtual-key code `VK_SHIFT`, then send another `WM_KEYDOWN` message with the letter's virtual-key code.

So, your code should look like this:

```
def post_keys(hwnd, i):
    win32api.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, wincon.VK_SHIFT, 0)
    win32api.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, i, 0)

    win32api.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYUP, i, 0)
    win32api.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYUP, wincon.VK_SHIFT, 0)
```

The full list of Virtual-key codes can be found at [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Remember they represent physical keyboard keys, so when you are unsure which code to send, just look at your keyboard to see how you would type a specific character. Keep in mind that the actual characters the keycodes are translated to will vary based on your selected keyboard layout.

For example, with the EN_US keyboard layout, to send "%", you would first send `VK_SHIFT`, then `0x35` (the "5" key).

Comment: Your last line makes it obvious that this depends on which keyboard layout you are using. For instance VK_SHIFT plus the "9" key produces a `)` on my keyboard (Spanish), but maybe a `(` on yours if it is English.

Comment: @Hyperboreus, yes, the MSDN page linked to mentions that for some of the key codes. You can use the [GetKeyNameText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646300%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to retrieve the key name for a given key code. However, using SendMessage with `WM_KEYDOWN` is really only suitable for basic key codes such as arrow keys. If you want to send arbitrary text strings as keyboard presses, you should use SendInput with the appropriately populated `KEYBDINPUT` structure (dwFlags should be set to `KEYEVENTF_UNICODE`), but that is not what the question asked.

Comment: Thanks alldayremix and Hyperboreus very much. Now it work well.